# Nodejs receiving empty data from angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new to angular and nodejs. I am sending data from angular to nodejs but i am only receiving empty array []. i have seen that some people were having the same issue and soulved by using

const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
};

I tried this option but it did not work for me. could anyone help me?

thank you.

Here is the angular code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import{Meal} from './meal.model';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MealService {

  selectedMeal: Meal;
  meal: Meal[];
  readonly baseURL = '';
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postMeal(m: Meal) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(m));
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, JSON.stringify(m));
    
  }
```

Here is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { MealService } from '../connection/meal.service';
import { Meal } from '../connection/meal.model';

declare var M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-meal',
  templateUrl: './meal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./meal.component.css'],
  providers:[MealService]
})
export class MealComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public mealService: MealService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form)
      form.reset();
      
    this.mealService.selectedMeal = {
      _id: "",
      item: "",
      price: 0
    }
  }
  

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value._id == "") {

      this.mealService.postMeal(form.value).subscribe((res) => {   
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.refreshMealList();
        M.toast({ html: 'Saved successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
```

nodejs Routes

```
const   express = require("express"),
        router = express.Router(),
        mealCtrl = require("./meal-controller");

router.post('/meals', mealCtrl.createMeal);
```

nodejs Cotroller

```
const Meal = require("./models/meal");
    
   exports.createMeal = function(req, res){
    let newmeal = new Meal(req.body);
    newmeal.save(function(err, meal){
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json(err);
        }
        res.json(meal);
    });
};
```

And .js file

```
const   http = require("http"),
        logger = require("morgan"),
        express = require("express"),
        bodyParcer = require("body-parser"),
        mongoose = require("mongoose");
        cors = require("cors");

let app = express();
let port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(bodyParcer.json());
app.use(require('./routes'));
app.use(logger("tiny"));
app.use(cors({origin: ''}));

const dbURI = "mongodb://localhost/test";

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .then((result) => console.log('connected to db'))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err)); 

app.listen(port, function(err){
    console.log("Listening on port: " + port)
});
```

Comment: So can you see the post with the correct payload in your network tab in the browser? Also, don’t stringify your payloads.

Comment: yea as @MikeOne mentioned don't stringify as http client already does that,

Comment: on the network tab i can only see the generated id without the data. when i remove the stringify i dont receive any data. not even the empty array.   
 thats what i get when using postman{"_id":"6271347dec75cdd8f08e9321","item":"meal","price":22,"__v":0},                 and thats what i receive when using angular {"_id":"62767fd6a2f1a6b2ef3c3043","__v":0}